# Why does my brew look cloudy

Tags: cloudy, clarity, problems, troubleshooting

i took a reading of my brew and the hydrometer is reading 1.010, it smells great to me but the beer looks cloudy not clear can someone help plzzzz

Comment: What kind of beer is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible that you haven't given the beer enough time to settle out.  A hydrometer reading of 1.010 may indicate that fermentation is done.  But there is likely still plenty of stuff still settling out.
I'd recommend moving the fermentor to someplace cooler than fermentation temps, as this will help promote the settling of stuff.  If you have a secondary fermentor you can rack to that, but I don't really think its necessary.

I let all my beers sit in primary for 10-14 days.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good related answers. Use the search.  Here are two to get you started.

- [Cleaner wort out of the Kettle](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/492/cleaner-wort-out-of-the-kettle)
- [How do you filter at home?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/how-do-you-filter-at-home)

Comment: hey thanx for the links and the advise